# What does the yellow progress bar in stock browser means, while rendering downloading web page?

Tags: browser

While rendering / downloading web page the stock browser shows moving yellow progress bar. It tends to start increasing from the left, at times increasing from the right, there are also gaps in the yellow bar, before finally completing rendering / downloading and disappearing. I'd love to understand what it all means.

Whatsmyuseragent.com gives ... 

"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; ViewPad7 Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1"

[image: Android browser progress bar]

[Android browser progress bar video on Picasa](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/i7H8XojxFK_SORleEMdiQhdASHfz5Ay8vFJKw2MPb4g?feat=directlink) at ...

00:01 shows short yellow bar from left

00:02 shows yellow bar from right

00:03 shows longer yellow bar from left

00:05 complete rendering, progress bar disappears

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen it come from the right, nor have I seen it "gap", but the progress bar is just that, it shows the download progress for the page that you about to view.

After you posted your screenshot and video, it looks like that the browser is seeing that you are on the Malaysian version of Google. If I am correct, the Malaysian is read from Right to Left, which would be why the progress bar loads from right to left.

If you just go to Google.com, it will load from left to right, or you have the default language on your device to be Malaysian, in which case, would default it to right to left.

Comment: The progress bar increasing from right is obvious on my Android browswer. FWIW, its user agent is ...
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; ViewPad7 Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1"
I can snap a video of the progress bar progressing if that helps.

Comment: A video or even a screenshot may help. There is an app on the market called "No Root ScreenShot It" - https://market.android.com/details?id=com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfullnoroot&hl=en that can take a screenshot. You can then edit your original question and add the image.

Comment: Added image and video, snapped with a cheap android phone. Sorry for the quality. Yet to root my ViewPad7 and get a free screenshot app.

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Comment: Malaysian (or Bahasa Malaysia) used roman alphabet and is read/written from left to right (not right to left). My Viewpad7 Android language setting is "English (United States). The progressing from both left and right sides occurs for all websites. So, I'm not sure your modified answer is the correct answer, yet. My other android device is still on Eclair 2.1, and that doesn't seem to exhibit this progressing from left and right. I'll see whether other Android device I can get hands on, shows the same ...

Comment: oh, it is? When I searched for Malaysian alphabet, the site I looked at said it was written right to left. And if you default language is English on the device, then I don't know why yours is loading from right to left... :)